# Use the a known solution of a DE to find a new solution of a similar DE

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Observe that  $ \displaystyle y=e^{x} $ is a solution of the equation 
$$
(x-1)y''(x)-(x)y'(x)+y=0
$$
Use this fact to find the general solution of 
$$
(x-1)y''(x)-(x)y'(x)+y=(x-1)^{2}\frac{\sin(x)}{x}
$$

Apparently, I am supposed to let the solution of the second DE =(unknown function)*(solution of 1st DE).  I've hit a wall.  Any help with this would be greatful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You let, as you said, $y=\,e^x$.  Then

$$y'=(w+w')e^x$$
$$y''=(w''+2 w'+w)e^x$$

You have to do the algebra and rearrange things, but you get a simpler equation for $w$:

$$w''+\frac{x-2}{x-1} w' = (x-1) e^{-x} \frac{\sin{x}}{x}$$

To solve this, you need to find an integrating factor that makes the LHS take the form

$$\frac{d}{dx}[q(x) w'(x)]$$

where you find $q(x)$ upon finding the integrating factor.  Then you can solve for $w'(x)$, which means you'll need to integrate once more to get $w(x)$.